# Is modulus of a complex function always non holomorphic?

Tags: holomorphic-functions

Let $f(z)$ be a complex function that is holomorphic on an open subset of the complex plane. Now, if we define another function $g(z)=|f(z)|^2$, can we say anything about the holomorphicity of $g(z)$ for arbitrary $f(z)$? Also, can you give examples where depending on the form of $f(z)$, the function $g(z)$ turns out to be holomorphic or otherwise?

Note: I am not a mathematician, so there may be mistakes in the statement of my problem. Please do point that out.

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann, qed.

Comment: @Did The form of $f(z)$ is arbitrary, so can't use Cauchy Riemann equations. In that case is it possible to say whether $g(z)$ is analytic?

Comment: Of course one can. First, what are $\Re g$ and $\Im g$?

Comment: @Did Oh yes, sure! $g(z)$ is then always non-holomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $g(z)=|f(z)|^2$ is a real valued function.

That is you have a function $u+iv$ for which $v=0$

Cauchy- Riemann theorem could be applied to make a decision regarding the function $g(z)$ being or not being holomorphic.